# Google Docs footer error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I got the below script for automatic "last edited" timestamp in the
footer of a Google Document.

```
function lastEdited() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var id = doc.getId();
  var file = Drive.Files.get(id);
  var footerSection = (doc.getFooter())?doc.getFooter():doc.addFooter();
  footerSection.clear();
  var userName = file.lastModifyingUserName;
  var date = file.modifiedDate;
  var text = '[Last edited by ' + userName + ' on ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date), 'GMT+5', 'YYYY/MM/dd hh:mm') + ']';
  var p = footerSection.insertParagraph(0,text);
  p.setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
}
```

But there is below mentioned error in this

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' (line 4, file "Code.gs")

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] What is the line 4? Have you already enable the Google Drive Advanced Service? What runtime are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the Drive API in the advanced Google service first:

[image]

From the script editor go to R*esources > Advanced Google service* and turn the Drive API on. Onces you've done that, you need to press the bug button to authenticate the script again.